# Patch 2nd Linux kernel: "module is in use"

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, patch, dkms

how to patch kernel with a DKMS module if the module is 'in use'?
The Kernel which should be used to get patched is not the one which is actual running on this machine. (uname -r)

It is about hpsa module, which needs to be in use.

Should'nt it be possible to patch only the newer not running kernel?

My steps so far:

```
[...]
dkms install --force -k 5.10.0-13-amd64 hpsa-dkms/1.1

modprobe -r hpsa -S 5.10.0-13-amd64
modprobe: FATAL: Module hpsa is in use.

lsmod | grep hpsa
hpsa                  110592  11
scsi_transport_sas     49152  1 hpsa
scsi_mod              262144  7 scsi_transport_sas,sd_mod,usb_storage,hpsa,uas,libata,sg
```

Comment: You have to check what is using it, which is not something the kernel tracks, I believe. Examples would be files or devices created by the module that are being used; or filesystems that are mounted.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
dkms install --force -k 5.10.0-13-amd64 hpsa-dkms/1.1
```

will build the kernel module for the `5.10.0-13-amd64` kernel and move it somewhere where `modprobe` can find it when running `5.10.0-13-amd64` kernel.

The command

```
modprobe -r hpsa -S 5.10.0-13-amd64
```

attempts to remove the `hpsa` kernel module from the currently running kernel. This is specifically removing it from the *current* kernel and not removing the kernel object file from the usual module directories that `modprobe` loads from. If you reboot into the `5.10.0-13-amd64` kernel, then you should hopefully be able to load the `hpsa` module that you built.

The in-kernel module only lasts as long as either it's removed from the kernel, or the kernel is removed (shutdown, `kexec`, etc.).